# How can I fill views using cycles?

Tags: android

How can I fill views using cycles. For example, I have a three element:

```
TextView tv_1, tv_2, tv_3
```

Can I do something like this?

```
for(int i=1; i<=3; i++){
    tv_{i}.setText(i);
}
```

Comment: For example, I can do this in Python.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question ??

Comment: I mean, Can I substitute tv_{i} on  tv_1, tv_2, tv_3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an List of textViews and run cycles/loop on it.

```
List<TextView> textViews = new ArrayList<>();
textViews.add(textView1);
textViews.add(textView2);
textViews.add(textView3);
```

after that just iterate through it :

```
for(int i=0 ;i <textViews.size(); i++)
{
   textViews.get(i).setText("text");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this.

```
TextView[] tvs = new TextView[3];

tvs[0] = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
tvs[1] = findViewById(R.id.tv2);
tvs[2] = findViewById(R.id.tv3);


for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
   tvs[i].setText(i);
}
```